# optimising aws hosted app that generates and serves files using caching

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-elasticache, serverless

I have an app composed of several microservices, all running as separate python lambda functions. The user-interface is a react app hosted on s3. The user inputs several variables which feed in to the serverless backend via API gateway, which generates a powerpoint file.

For a given set of variables the powerpoint output will be identical each time. As such, it makes no sense to regenerate and store the file each time. I looked into https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/ but am unsure on how to integrate it here. Should I be storing these powerpoint files in s3 and only generating if the file is not already present, then serve a link pointing to the s3 bucket? This seems slow and cumbersome. What would be the most efficient way to serve up these powerpoint files repetitively?

Comment: Are you using API gateway to access lambda function?

Comment: @sirajpathan Yes

Answer (score 0):

You can use API gateway caching to cache data.
Goto api gateway => Click on "Stages" => stage_name => "Settings" tab => "Enable API caching"

More details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html

see below image [image]

Comment: And so where would the powerpoint files I am generating be stored?

Comment: what is the size of ppt? Are there too many multiple files generated based on different types of user requests?

Comment: around 500-600kb per file and there could be thousands of them

Comment: If you are using API gateway caching then you don't need to store in S3, but if you still have scenarios when API gateway cache is expired and you still need some second level of caching in that case you can store files in S3 to reduce lambda compute time.

Comment: @Ludo Does it Work?